# Excel - How to get cetain letters to count as a 0 ?

Tags: excel

I have a system that keeps an overview of the positions in the F1 season and I was wondering how i can get DNS and DNF to count as 0 in the total amount of laps started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add an additional column use the formula `=IF(OR(B5="DNF",B5="DNS"),0,B5)` and replace B5 with the cell containing DNS or DNF.   Add up the totals and hide the column containing the formula

or

`=SUM(<FROM>:<TO>)` will ignore non-numeric cells in the range

or

Create a user defined function following these [instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel)

Add these functions:

```vb
Public Function ToLapStatus(value As String) As Long
  Dim result As Long
  result = 0
  If (value = "DNF" Or value = "DNS") Then
    result = 0
  Else
    result = Val(value)
  End If
  ToLapStatus = result
End Function

Public Function SumLapStatus(Data1 As Range) As Long
  Dim result As Long
  result = 0
  For Each cell In Data1
    result = result + ToLapStatus(cell.value)
  Next
  SumLapStatus = result
End Function
```

Then you can use `=SumLapStatus(<your-range)` to calculate the total